# Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos and protolite-well-known-types

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

When I try to add `com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1` dependency to my build.gradle file, I am getting this error. How can I resolve this issue?

```
 Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.31.0
 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.31.0) and protolite-well-known-
types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file(s)?

Comment: try adding this in your app build.gradle:
`configurations.implementation{
    exclude group: "com.google.firebase", module: "protolite-well-known-types"
}
`